# MySQL Nested Query HAVING Field

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to configure a subquery, but am having some difficulty with aggregation/grouping.  The subquery selects a count based on the average value.  However, placing the `AVG(response) >= target` condition in the *WHERE* block results in a "Invalid use of group function" error.  Placing the condition in the subquery's *HAVING* block works, except that it requires the *target* variable has to appear in the *SELECT* block with the COUNT, which results in an "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error.  A copy of the query is below.

I'm familiar with both nested queries and aggregate functions, but this particular combination is refusing to cooperate.  It seems like there should be a keyword for "select this field for comparison/HAVING but don't return it", or maybe I'm just mis-formulating the query.  Unfortunately, this is being run by BIRT reporting software, so I can't just (to the best of my knowledge) grab the raw data and aggregate manually.

The query (slightly pruned for clarity) is below:

```
SELECT 
    c.job_competency_id,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(ar1.assessment_result_id) 
        FROM 
            recent_assessment AS ra1,
            assessment_result AS ar1,
            client_job_competency AS jc1
        WHERE 
            ar1.assessment_id = a.assessment_id
            AND ra1.assessment_id = ar1.assessment_id
            AND ar1.job_competency_id = jc1.job_competency_id
            AND ar1.job_competency_id = c.job_competency_id
            AND AVG(ar1.response) >= jc1.target
        GROUP BY jc1.job_competency_id
    ) AS n_meets
FROM 
    recent_assessment AS ra,
    assessment AS a,
    assessment_result AS ar,
    client_job_competency AS jc,
    job_competency AS c,
    master_competency AS mc 
WHERE 
    a.client_id = ?
    AND ra.assessment_id = a.assessment_id
    AND ar.assessment_id = a.assessment_id
    AND c.job_competency_id = ar.job_competency_id
    AND c.master_competency_id = mc.master_competency_id
    AND jc.job_competency_id = c.job_competency_id;
```

In case it matters, the alternative subquery is here:

```
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(ar1.assessment_result_id),
            jc1.target
        FROM 
            recent_assessment AS ra1,
            assessment_result AS ar1,
            client_job_competency AS jc1
        WHERE 
            ar1.assessment_id = a.assessment_id
            AND ra1.assessment_id = ar1.assessment_id
            AND ar1.job_competency_id = jc1.job_competency_id
            AND ar1.job_competency_id = c.job_competency_id
        GROUP BY jc1.job_competency_id
        HAVING AVG(ar1.response) >= jc1.target
    ) AS n_meets
```

If you read this far, thank you for taking a look.  Please let me know if anything requires clarification.  Hopefully I just made a boneheaded mistake somewhere.

Comment: This is a correlated subquery, so it should always return 1 row. Why do you need to use `HAVING` to filter it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an aggregation function in the `WHERE` clause, because it doesn't process the aggregation until after all the rows are selected, which is what the `WHERE` clause does.

To solve your problem with `HAVING` requiring you to select the column to compare with, you can wrap it in another level of subquery. Then the outer query can just return the one column you want to put into the `SELECT` list.

```
(SELECT n_meets
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(ar1.assessment_result_id) AS n_meets,
        jc1.target
    FROM 
        recent_assessment AS ra1,
        assessment_result AS ar1,
        client_job_competency AS jc1
    WHERE 
        ar1.assessment_id = a.assessment_id
        AND ra1.assessment_id = ar1.assessment_id
        AND ar1.job_competency_id = jc1.job_competency_id
        AND ar1.job_competency_id = c.job_competency_id
    GROUP BY jc1.job_competency_id
    HAVING AVG(ar1.response) >= jc1.target
) AS x) AS n_meets
```